# Valgrind Errors - Conditional Jump or move depends on uninitialised values

Tags: arrays, c, error-handling, initialization, valgrind

[img of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGxrs.png)

Above is an error I have been getting, in relation to this line in my program:

```
storedData[k] = min(dist[index1][k],dist[index2][k]);
```

Now here is the surrounding functions to this line:

```
for(int k = 0; k <arraySize; k++){
    if(k!= index1 && k != index2){
        if(method == SINGLE_LINKAGE){
            storedData[k] = min(dist[index1][k],dist[index2][k]);
        } else {
            storedData[k] = max(dist[index1][k],dist[index2][k]);
        }
    }
}
```

Now after playing around with it for quite a while, I realised that the issue it has is with the incrementing 'k' variable in the for loop. More specifically it is worried that when used as an index in dist, the value returned will be uninitialised. Now in terms of functionality, my program works fine and does everything I want it to do. More notably, I have also initialised this function elsewhere in a helper function which is why this confuses me more. I have initialised all the values from index 0-arraysize which in my head means this should never be an issue. Im not sure if maybe this is caused because its done outside of the main function or something. Regardless it keeps giving me grief and I would like to fix it.

Comment: Your problem is in the "dist" array. Some of the values in it are uninitialized (potentially random) data. Make sure you initialize the whole thing with the proper data.

Comment: I have made nested for loops that go from 0 - arraysize setting dist[i][j] = 0. Yet it still doesnt work,

Comment: Please do not post links to images of text.  Rather copy/paste the text into your question

Answer (score 0):

You need to work back from the error to its origin. Even if you are initializing your arrays, it is possible that something is 'uninitializing' them again afterwards. `memcheck` does not flag uninitialized data when it is copied, only when it affects the outcome.

So in pseudo-code you might have

```
Array arr;
Scalar uninit; // never initialized

init_array(arr);

// do some stuff
arr[3] = uninit; // no error here

for (i = 1 to arr.size)
    store[i] = max(arr[i], arr[i-1]; // errors for i == 3 and 4
```

There are two things that you could try. Firstly, try some 'printf' debugging, something like

```
for(int k = 0; k <arraySize; k++) {
    if(k!= index1 && k != index2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "DEBUG: k %d index1 %d index2 %d\n", k, index1, index2);
        // as before
```

Then run Valgrind without a log file. You should then be able to see which indices cause the error(s).

Next, try using ggbserver. Run valgrind in one terminal with

`valgrind --vgdb-error=0 prog args`

and then run gdb in a second terminal to attach (see the text that is output in the 1st terminal for the commands to use).

You can then use gdb as usual (except no 'run') to control your guest app, with the additional ability to run [valgrind monitor commands](https://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core-adv.html#manual-core-adv.gdbserver).